# Fastest algorithm to find all the possible paths of length $n$ from a give node in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, counting

I am trying to find the fastest algorithm to find all the possible paths of length $N$ from a given node in a directed graph.

My solution is to do a modification of breadth first search from the given node for $N$ iteration. Its time complexity is around $\theta(V+E)$. But the problem is $|V|$ & $|E|$ becomes exponential because as long as there is an edge, the same node can be visited again.

Can there be a solution of this problem with polynomial time complexity? It seems this problem has optimal substructure solution. Is there any solution using dynamic approach?

Comment: How would V and E be exponential?

Comment: @oerpli Paths allowed in every directions. I am not coloring the nodes unlike BFS. I can visit the same node again as long as there is an edge.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10949/all-paths-of-less-than-a-given-length-in-a-directed-graph-between-couple-of-node. See this if it help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard, since the Hamiltonian Path problem is a special case of this problem where we set N=n and check whether the answer is strictly greater than zero.

This problem is actually #P-hard wich is believed to be strictly harder than NP.

The version of the problem where you only look for the existence of such a path is called the longest path problem. A well-known problem in theory. It is fixed-parameter tractable when parameterized by the length of the path (check Parameterized Algorithms book by Cygan et al for description and methods).

Comment: Is there any approximate solution to this problem in polynomial time?

Comment: But I solved it using dynamic programming where I'm storing paths covered so far & keep attaching them with the edges of next step. Is my solution wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if you are keeping all the paths in your dynamic programming table or only their length. Keeping all the paths is already exponential, since there can be exponential many paths (You already stated that in your answer). This does not contradicts the hardness of the problem, since the hardness proof shows there there is probably no polynomial time algorithm. There is always exponential time algorithms for NP and #P problems since they are contained in EXP.

Comment: Please let me know if there is a vague part of the answer. You already stated that you algorithm is exponential which we usually try to avoid. I showed that probably exponential is the best we can achieve. Does that answer your question or am I not on the right track?

Comment: Your answer does help me. Give me some more time to think on this.

Comment: There are also a couple or randomized approximations for counting Hamiltonian Cycles. I don't know how applicable they are for your case.

Comment: Please share whatever relevant you can share.

Comment: I strongly think the problem does not admit a constant factor deterministic approximation. However, there seems to be many randomized approaches online mostly for greater factor and for counting Hamiltonian cycles. I don't know if they are extendable to longest path.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/336517

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/336517

Comment: OP states that the same node can be visited multiple times, so the problem of finding longest such path is not NP-hard. There always exists such path in a directed graph that has a cycle, and in acyclic graphs it can be solved with dynamic programming in linear time.

Comment: I think he meant using different paths (total number of occurrences of a vertex)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that. In the case that you consider, my answer from cstheory SE should be relevant: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45654/finding-simple-fixed-length-paths-in-directed-graphs/

Comment: Your technique is randomised. There are deterministic ways using fast set convultion. The book I referenced describes them well. However, he is looking for the counting version of the problem not the decision one

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that the more advanced techniques for longest path could also enumerate them efficiently. Though I still think that the color coding technique is valuable, because its conceptually simple.

Comment: Oh  no I did not mean that. Both do not enumerate them that is what I am saying. Both only solve the decision version that is why they do not answer the question heree

Answer (score 1):

The above answer considers the version of this problem where vertices cannot be visited multiple times. However it seems that the intention of the question is that vertices could be visited multiple times.

The number of such paths can be exponential in |V| and |E|, so they cannot be listed in polynomial time.

The problem of counting the number of such paths is equivalent to computing the $N$th power of the adjacency matrix of the graph. If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph, then the value of the cell $(i, j)$ of $A^N$ is the number of $N$-length paths from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.

While in general such paths cannot be listed in polynomial time, they however can be listed with polynomial delay (i.e. outputting a new path in polynomial time). For all lengths $k \le N$, compute by dynamic programming numbers $cnt[v][k]$, which represents the number of paths of length $k$ from the starting vertex to vertex $v$. Now such paths can be extracted by traversing this dynamic programming structure backwards. If $cnt[v][N]$ is positive, find vertex $u$ such that there is edge from $u$ to $v$, and $cnt[u][N-1]$ is positive. Extract the $N-1$ length path to $u$ recursively, add $v$ as the last vertex of the path and subtract $cnt[v][N]$ by one.

Comment: +1. Yeah. The solution I came up with Using dynamic programming  didn't reduce the time but it was actually  giving new path in polynomial delay. Thanks to give me clarity. :)